# Display from latitude/longitude

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make a WPF application that takes a latitude/longitude value and then displays this point on a map via a marker.

I have found a few examples like this: http://gmaps.codeplex.com/

But it doesn't pinpoint the exact latitude/longitude, just the nearest road? So I was wondering how I could achieve this?

Comment: Do you already have the map? Or do you want to use some service to get the map too?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using for this? Hard to find the problem when we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I don't have a solution yet, which why I'm asking - I don't have a map either, I wondered how people can generate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I've used the Bing Maps SDK a good bit and have found that it works well.  Check out their API.  It's pretty simple, with lots of examples.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27165

A pretty good example that ought to accomplish what you're looking for:

http://elegantcode.com/2011/08/26/build-an-earthquake-application-with-bing-maps-wpf-control-beta/

Comment: Do you know how you can text to the pins?

Comment: @Mike, The pins don't have to be those objects.  You can add any UI Element, so you could just make your own control (I don't believe they have something out of the box that does this, but that's why they allow any UIElement).